# How to pass a set of composite types (UDTs) in PostgreSQL using JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, jboss, composite-types

We are migrating from Oracle to PostgreSQL Enterprise DB and we have a stored procedure that accepts table-like structure. We used STRUCT with Oracle and it worked very well. Now this table is configured in PostgreSQL as UDT containing table of other UDT-s and it works hen being invoked from PostgreSQL layer.

I can't find a proper support or documentation on how to pass composite type as collection of composite types or array of composite types using PostgreSQL JDBC driver.

I was able to invoke the procedure by passing my implementation of PGobject.
My `getValue()` method converts the object data to the string of following format:

> {row(key,1596156006),row(dataHeader2TDataHeader,2782),row(identifier01,20373833),
>   ...}

But I get error "malformed array literal" from PostgreSQL.

The PostgreSQL version is 9.3.1, JDK 1.6, JBoss 3.2.8

Comment: Are `key`, `dataHeader2TDataHeader`, `identifier01` all supposed to be column names? If so, they are in the wrong place. If not, they should at least be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

You have basically a few options in PostgreSQL:

1. Create your own string representation and write a parser in C, pl/perl, pl/pgsql, or the like.
2. Use ROW() and ARRAY[] constructors, or
3. Use raw data formats.
4. JSON (however this has limits!)

If you are going to write your own string representation, you need to pay close attention to how it is parsed on input and output.  You could go so far as to make your own types and not use composite types.  This has some useful benefits in terms of ensuring that you always know your input and output formulas.

ROW() and ARRAY[] constructors can be used together.  In this case you might:

```
 ARRAY[ROW(1, 'foo')::bar, ROW(2, 'baz'), ROW(3, 'foobar,')]
```

Finally there is raw data formats.  These use nested CSV (including double quoting) with {csv} representing an array and (csv) representing a row.  The above would be this:

```
 '{"(1,foo)","(2,baz)","(3,""foobar,"")"}'
```